# Simulate a Locally Attached USB Drive that passes files to a Network Drive

Tags: networking, usb, shared, disk, drive

I've found a lot of posts explaining how to access a USB attached drive over the network, but this is a whole different scenario. I am currently afraid that it can't be done.

Our church has a video mixer that we use to broadcast our worship services over the Internet. The device will also store the video on an attached USB drive. After the service is complete I have to disconnect the USB drive from the video mixer, plug it into our server and copy the video file to the shared network drive, then disconnect the USB drive from the server and reconnect it to the video mixer. Reminds me of what was commonly called the "Sneaker Net" back in the day when files were transferred between PCs via floppy disks.

I believe I'm looking for is a device that will appear as a USB disk drive when plugged into the video mixer making it think that it is directly connected to a drive when in fact it's connected to a network share on our server. Imagine what you could do if you could plug a USB cable into your phone and connect it to a shared drive on your network.

I'm getting tired of shuffling the USB drive back and forth after every service. If anyone knows of such a device please let me know where I can find it.

Thanks.

Howard

Comment: I wonder if you could pull the broadcast from the internet stream to the server

Comment: Possible, but the quality of the video would not be as high as the original as my streaming host provider transcodes the video. Furthermore, my internet bandwidth is limited and I've reserved half of the bandwidth to push the stream up to our streaming host and already pull two streams, one from our web site and one from Facebook, for monitoring purposes. Pulling another stream to capture the video on another device may impact our existing streams.

Comment: I have the same problem - I have an oscilloscope that can write to USB.. but I would like to plug in a USB stick that will allow it to write to a networked folder (ie. directly to my PC). Must be something out there surely.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need, and the best I could come up with is a USB over Ethernet extender.

At least this way I could put the host side into the otherwise dumb device (a windows embedded host in my case) and keep the other end near me, where it was convenient to move a USB thumb drive from the extender to my computer, and back.